# Spring 2.x.x and Java 8 Implemented Spring Batch REST/HTTP Item Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, spring-batch

Does anyone successfully implemented a REST/HTTP ItemWriter with Spring Batch while the integrating HTTP Endpoint is in SYNC implementation?

I did some work around using Retrofit library. It doesn't increase the performance that much, as the client is the only one who is calling in asynchronous. The other service is running with Apache Camel while they are waiting for a request in REST controller.

```
MyService -> MyHttpItemWriter -> ExternalRestController
```

WHERE:

| MyService | MyHttpItemWriter | ExternalRestController |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Read from Kafka and process the data | Send the clean data via REST call | REST Controller will process the data via Apache camel |

```
for(Object request : requests){
 Call<ObjResponse> callAsync = service.sendRequest(request);
 
 callAsync.enqueue(new Callback<UserApiResponse>() 
 {
     
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ObjResponse> call, Response<ObjResponse> response) 
    {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) 
        {
            ObjResponse apiResponse = response.body();
 
            //API response
            System.out.println(apiResponse);
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Request Error :: " + response.errorBody());
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `Does anyone successfully implemented a REST/HTTP ItemWriter with Spring Batch while the integrating HTTP Endpoint is in SYNC implementation?` What do you mean by `successfully` and `SYNC implementation`?

Comment: Is it possible with spring batch Item Writer to POST a 2000 Asynchronous request to a Synchronous endpoint in a few seconds, without the writer waiting for the response?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible with spring batch Item Writer to POST a 2000 Asynchronous request to a Synchronous endpoint in a few seconds, without the writer waiting for the response?

Yes, you would need an `AsyncItemWriter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors

Comment: It doesn't seem to stop the thread from waiting on the response due to HTTP is the protocol being used in the connection. It just holds on to the thread then close it after it received the response. But let me see if I can do some more work around in this implementation. Thanks!